# Delete whole groups or group members

Tags: r

I am working on a big dataset and have got a problem with data cleaning. My data set looks like this:

```
data <- cbind (group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), 
               member = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5), 
               score = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))
```

I just want to keep the group in which the sum of score is equal to 1 and remove the whole group in which the sum of score is equal to 0. For the group in which the sum of the score is greater than 1, e.g., sum of score = 3, I want to randomly select two group members with score equal to 1 and remove them from the group. Then the data may look like this:

```
newdata <- cbind (group = c(1,1,1,3,3,4,4,4), 
                  member = c(1,2,3,2,3,1,3,5), 
                  score = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0))
```

Does anybody can help me get this done?

Comment: Are you always removing two group members if the sum of score is greater than 1?

Comment: If the sum of score is greater than 1 for a group, I would like to ramdoly select one member who has score 1 and keep it in the group and remove other members who have score 1 from the group. In this case, I will keeep the group members who have score 0 in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function that combines the various manipulations for you. Here is one such function, heavily commented:

```
process <- function(x) {
    ## this adds a vector with the group sum score
    x <- within(x, sumScore <- ave(score, group, FUN = sum))
    ## drop the group with sumScore == 0
    x <- x[-which(x$sumScore == 0L), , drop = FALSE]
    ## choose groups with sumScore > 1
    ## sample sumScore - 1 of the rows where score == 1L
    foo <- function(x) {
        scr <- unique(x$sumScore) ## sanity & take only 1 of the sumScore
        ## which of the grups observations have score = 1L
        want <- which(x$score == 1L)
        ## want to sample all bar one of these
        want <- sample(want, scr-1)
        ## remove the selected rows & retun
        x[-want, , drop = FALSE]
    }
    ## which rows are samples with group sumScore > 1
    want <- which(x$sumScore > 1L)
    ## select only those samples, split up those samples by group, lapplying foo
    ## to each group, then rbind the resulting data frames together
    newX <- do.call(rbind,
                    lapply(split(x[want, , drop = FALSE], x[want, "group"]),
                           FUN = foo))
    ## bind the sampled sumScore > 1L on to x (without sumScore > 1L)
    newX <- rbind(x[-want, , drop = FALSE], newX)
    ## remove row labels
    rownames(newX) <- NULL
    ## return the data without the sumScore column
    newX[, 1:3]
}
```

that with your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), 
                  member = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5), 
                  score = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))
```

gives:

```
> set.seed(42)
> process(dat)
  group member score
1     1      1     0
2     1      2     1
3     1      3     0
4     3      1     1
5     3      2     0
6     4      1     0
7     4      3     1
8     4      5     0
```

Which is I think what was wanted.

**Update:** In `process()` above, the internal function `foo()` could be rewritten to sample only 1 row and remove the others. I.e replace `foo()` with the one below:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    scr <- unique(x$sumScore) ## sanity & take only 1 of the sumScore
    ## which of the grups observations have score = 1L
    want <- which(x$score == 1L)
    ## want to sample just one of these
    want <- sample(want, 1)
    ## return the selected row & retun
    x[want, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

They are the same operations essentially but `foo()` that selects just 1 row makes the intended behaviour explicit; we want to select 1 row at random from those with score == 1L, rather than sample `scr-1` values.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works very well and your notes with the code is helpful. Thank you again.

Comment: Your updated code is also doing great. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a function that does what you want it to.  Then use `ddply` and split by `group`.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  if(sum(x$score)==1) {
    return(x)
  } else if(sum(x$score)==0) {
    return(data.frame())
  } else {
    row.names(x) <- NULL
    score.1 <- sample(as.integer(row.names(x[x$score==1,])), nrow(x[x$score==1,])-1)
    return(x[-score.1,])
  }
}

library(plyr)
ddply(as.data.frame(dat), .(group), myfun)

  group member score
1     1      1     0
2     1      2     1
3     1      3     0
4     3      1     1
5     4      1     0
6     4      2     1
7     4      3     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this is not exactly what I want. for the group 3, I want to keep the second member who has score 0. For the group 4, I want to keep just one member has score 1 and the ohter one who has score 0. Please see my "newdata" in my simple example above. t

Comment: @user187454 But Justin _has_ done 90% of the work _for_ you here. All that's left is to tweak the function slightly.

Comment: see my edits to the function in my answer... and what @joran said :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ugroups<-unique(data[,1])
scores<-sapply(ugroups,function(x){sum(data[,1]==x & data[,3]==1)})
data[data[,1]%in%ugroups[scores>0],]
....... etc
```

will give you the cumulative scores for each group etc